# Conditional CSS height for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, conditional-statements

Is there a way to rewrite this code so when the screen is full screen and tablet then the blue-cus-box margin-top is -175 and if the screen is, for example, iPhone 10 or other mobile devices then the margin-top is -150?

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

.blue-cus-box {
  margin-top: -175px !important;
  z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: You should need to use relative units

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer.  Looking for an example code or something that could be customized to make this happen if possible.  I am very new in CSS

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just using a media query? The below snippet would set the margin-top to -175px on any screen size over 768px. A guide to using media queries in CSS can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

```css
.blue-cus-box {
  margin-top: -150px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .blue-cus-box {
    margin-top: -175px;
  }
}
```